# I want to get the most frequently clicked button as an item in the listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to make in which there are a series of buttons. Each button is clicked, then theres is a label beside it which records the count of hits the button gets.

Then I am able to get the greatest integer from that collection (greatest number of times a button was clicked). So I get the number, I'm confused on how to associate the highest number to the most clicked button so that I can automatically add an item in a listbox which shows the most frequently used button.

```
//////--Code to import the greatest integer of all the collection (clicked more times)---

`Private Sub Button1_Click_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As `enter code here`System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
1.  Dim nums() As Integer = {x1.Text, x2.Text, x3.Text, x4.Text, x5.text}
2.     Dim qry = From n As Integer In nums Order By n Descending
3.        For Each n As Integer In qry
4.            listbox1.Items.Add(n)
5.  Next
6. End Sub`


//////---code to get the single number which was greater than every other in the collection///-

`Private Sub Button2_Click_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
1. Dim nums() As Integer = {x1.Text, x2.Text, x3.Text, x4.Text, x5.text}
2. Dim qry = From n As Integer In nums Order By n Descending
3.        Dim res As Integer = nums.Max.ToString
4.        For Each i As Integer In nums
5.            If i > res Then res = i
6.            Label120.Text = res.ToString
7.        Next
8.        Return
9. End Sub`
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you get any error? Does the work?

Answer (score 1):

First define a class that will hold references to the buttons and labels.

```
Public Class ClickTracker
    Public Property Button As Button 
    Public Property Label as Label
    Public Property ClickCount as Integer

    Public Sub New(button as Button, label as Label)

        Me.Button = button
        Me.Label = label
        Me.ClickCount = 0
        AddHandler Me.Button.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick

    End Sub

    Public Sub ButtonClick (sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.ClickCount = Me.ClickCount + 1
        Me.Label.Text = Me.ClickCount.ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, the class takes references to your button+label pairs, and wires up an event handler for the button click.

Now define a collection in your form that will hold all the buttons you want to track.

```
Dim clickTrackers = New List(Of ClickTracker) From {
    {Me.Button1, Me.Label1},
    {Me.Button2, Me.Label2},
    ....ect
```

Thats all you need to do. At any time you can query against the list to see which buttons have how many clicks, completely independent of the rest of your logic.

You'll have to excuse my VB, I've been doing C# for so long I forgot a lot about the language, but this should be close enough.

Comment: Elegant (and scalable) solution.

Comment: Every good developer should be prepared to spend a little time to ensure solid deign upfront and avoid suffering during maintenance.

Comment: And a simple naming pattern doesn't require a lot of maintenance and a lot less time up front and a lot less resources.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is decide on a common naming pattern for the buttons(btnABC01,btnABC02,btnABC03,etc.) and the labels(lblABC01,lblABC02,lblABC03).  And set all the labels to an initial value of 0.

Now declare a common click event handler for the buttons and use the AddHandler method in the Form.Load event handler to assign that handler to each of the buttons

```
For Each b as Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
    If b.Name.Contains("ABC") Then
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    End If
Next
```

Now in the click event handler declare a temporary button to equal the button that was clicked(`Dim ClickedButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)`).  Do the same with the corresponding label and increment its value

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ClickedButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim LabelToSet As Label = DirectCast(Me.Controls("lblABC" + CilckedButton.Name.Substring(ClickedButton.Name.Length - 2)), Label)
    LabelToSet.Text = (Val(LabelToSet.Text) + 1).ToString
End Sub
```

Then `Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label).Max` should find the label with the highest number

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a poor design, because you are forced to use names for your buttons and labels that does not reflect the actual purpose for the button/label.